# Compute global motion opencv 2.4.x C++

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, motion-detection

Here are two images, one captured before an action has been made by the surgeon and the other afterwards.

Before: 
[image]

After:
[image]

Difference: (After - Before) + 128. (The addition of 128 is just to have a better image)
[image]

As pointed to by the white arrows, there has been a global motion affecting all the objects.

**So, I need to estimate it in order to get more valuable information on what's happening in the scene.**

I already knew that `OpenCV 3.0` helps in this context where it's implemented some methods that estimate the dominant motion between two images or two list of points. But I'm using so far `OpenCV 2.4.x` because I have dependencies with libraries already installed on my machine so I'm looking for alternative solutions or any other code that does what I want.

Comment: I'll share a link [here](http://study.marearts.com/search/label/Trash%20dumping%20detection). It pertains to a video, not a before/after image pair, but perhaps it could give you an idea. I would suggest skimming through the other posts on that blog, there may be something useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a [dense optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html) algorithm:

The result for

```
cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback(img1, img2, flowField, 0.5, 3, 10, 5, 5, 1.1)
```

is the following flow field where you clearly see the changes: [image]

As for the global motion detection:

- If the global motion is very small (as in your example) you can just threshold the motion vectors: throw small values away.
- If it is larger, find the dominant motion vector and subtract it from all of your vectors. Then threshold to throw small values away

Comment: how did you get exactly this image?

Comment: Perhaps using this - https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/fback.cpp

Comment: Yes. I think I swapped the image order but using the images posted above this is the result. The configuration was ``cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback(previousImage, image, flowField, 0.5, 3, 10, 5, 5, 1.1)``

Comment: but I'm not really able to understand how could you get this image? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750415/optical-flow-ignore-sparse-motions/34892970#34892970) is what I'm getting

Comment: the link shows a sparse optical flow approach (e.g. the flow of several keypoints). The Farneback Optical Flow works directly on the image and thus returns a flow vector for each pixel

Comment: I know.. I just meant take a look over the question and not the answer so you get what I mean by not being able to reproduce the same figure you got.